# RelativeLayout Elements are incorrectly overlapping

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, overlays

I'm trying to build a part of a Android View Programmatically, but unfortunately I'm having some problems with the `RelativeLayout`. it makes my `Elements` overlay on eachother

This is my Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.insertnew_layout);
    LinearLayout ll =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container); 

    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
    tl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


        // fill content
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {   

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
        rl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView score = new TextView(this);
        score.setText(""+i);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpScore = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        lpScore.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        score.setLayoutParams(lpScore);

        TextView description = new TextView(this);
        description.setText("this is my description");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpDescription = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        lpDescription.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, score.getId());

        description.setLayoutParams(lpDescription);

        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpCheckbox = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        lpCheckbox.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        checkbox.setLayoutParams(lpCheckbox);

        rl.addView(score);
        rl.addView(description);
        rl.addView(checkbox);
        tl.addView(rl);

    }

    ll.addView(tl);
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: output in javacode]

As you can see, the "description" is on top of of the "score".

Here is the same code in xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tableLayoutTextEntry" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRowTextEntry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="score" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/score"
            android:text="description" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="select" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

And here is what it looks like in xml:

[image: output in xml]

As you can see, in xml, the toRightOf-command works as expected - the description is to the right of the score

How is that possible? Shouldnt the line

`lpDescription.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, score.getId());`

do the same thing?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to have the layout created in code?

Comment: @Egor yes exactly, even he can easily implement this by defining **custom adapter for ListView**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are calling it, `score.getId()` will return -1 (invalid), because it has not been added yet to the screen with the whole layout processed. 
You will have to set the id manually with `setId()` before calling `getId()` and it should all work fine.